# Ceiling radiant heat

Tags: ceiling, heat

Each room has its own thermostat and heater. The bathroom hasn't stopped but isn't working correctly. When I touch the ceiling I can feel heat but the room doesn't get warm. I'm trying to fix this issue myself and cheaply as possible. Any answers/ideas/ things to try would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you add some more details and/or pictures? And, props for [taking our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) before posting; few newbies do.

Answer (score 1):

I live in the Pacific Northwest where ceiling cable heat used to be very popular. When I have found heating problems with not getting hot enough where it did heat properly in the past it has always been the thermostat with 1 exception. The 1 exception was a parallel cable set in a large room where a swagger lamp toggle bolt was drilled through 1 of the cables. Other than that my experience has always been bad contacts in the thermostat for partial heat.

Comment: Ed Beal: I too am in the great PNW. I had an employee who had ceiling heat, but she was smart enough to call an electrician every time she wanted to penetrate her ceiling for whatever reason.   May I politely ask what part of the PNW you are at?  Yeah, that questions borders on the chitchat we're not supposed to do here, but I was just wondering.  I respect your expertise and experience as much greater than mine.

Comment: Lane county Oregon  now have mostly worked in Benton, and Lynn  for the last 25 years and Portland for a while prior.